# How to reload my nginx server through cron or through node.js script instead of login from shell?

Tags: node.js, shell, nginx, cron

Previously I was using Apache server where redirect URL was getting created dynamically.

1. How to implement that in nginx server? I mean I have to restart/reload the nginx server again to implement that.
2. How to overcome my problem? How do I reload my nginx server through cron or through Node.js script instead of login from shell?

How to make it dynamic?

Comment: Looks like a typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/274118)

Comment: Describe your *real* problem

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically created redirect? Was it generated .htaccess or something another? May be, redirecting by script? Reloading web server automatically is a very bad practise.

Comment: in our application we create redirect url in our apache server like for alex we provide then ourcompany.com/alex what we do we write redirect url .n .htaccess like Redirect 301 /alex http://www.ourcompany.com/bms_clients/alex  mean after writting in .htaccess through fs we dont have to restart or reload apache but in nginx its not working mean we have to reload nginx even after writting location /alex{
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.ourcompany.com/bms_clients/alex/ redirect;
    } how to implement it from cron , mean how can i reload nginx from script or any other way to implement this